# Появились полоски между тайлами

Tags: unity3d

появились полоски между тайлами. Сами тайлы ставлю при помощи Tilemap. Все было нормально и без полосок, но после выхода из юнити, когда запустила проект снова, появились такие полоски, при этом ничего не трогала и не изменяла. Можете подсказать в чем дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить компонент **Composite Collider 2D**.
На **Tilemap Collider 2D** поставьте галочку **[v] used by composite**.

[См. документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CompositeCollider2D.html).